# python singleton decorator occur TypeError: 'A' object is not callable

Tags: python, singleton, decorator

here's the code:

```
def singleton(cls):
    # https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#The_Sublime_Singleton
    instance = cls()
    instance.__call__ = lambda: instance
    return instance


@singleton
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
```

The decorator is copied from python official wiki

when i run the following code:

```
a = A()
```

will raise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx", line ab, in yyy
    a = A()
TypeError: 'A' object is not callable
```

I'm using python 2.7.13.

Comment: The snippet *can't work*, because you can't put a `__call__` method on an instance. It is always looked up as `type(instance).__call__(instance)`, see the duplicate.

Comment: I've removed that example from the wiki, it is fatally flawed.